# Is the group of symplectomorphisms of a symplectic manifold the symplectic group?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, symplectic-geometry

The group of symplectomorphisms of a symplectic manifold $M$ is a subgroup of the group of diffeomorphisms $GL(n)$, actually it is a subgroup of $SL(n)$. My question is whether this group of symplectomorphisms is actually $Sp(n) \subset SL(n) \subset GL(n)$. On the other hand I read that the group of symplectomorphisms is larger than the isometry group of $M$ which is contradictory.

Answer (score 3):

The group of *linear* symplectomorphisms from an $n$-dimensional symplectic *vector space* to itself is a subgroup of $GL(n)$, namely $Sp(n)$, but the group of symplectomorphisms from an $n$-dimensional symplectic *manifold* to itself, $\operatorname{Sympl}(M, \omega)$ is not contained in $GL(n)$. In fact, $\operatorname{Sympl}(M, \omega)$ is an infinite-dimensional Lie group.

---

I just realised that you said that $GL(n)$ is the group of diffeomorphisms. That is not what $GL(n)$ denotes, it denotes the [general linear group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group).

Comment: Small correction: The group of _linear_ symplectomorphisms from an $n$-dimensional symplectic vector space to itself is a subgroup of $GL(n)$. The group of all symplectomorphisms, even in that case, is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: @JackLee: Thanks for that. I meant symplectomorphisms which respect the vector space structure. I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese the group of diffeomorphisms I had the impression it is given by elements of $GL(n)$. For example, in General Relativity, coordinate transformations (which are differ's) can be grouped in $GL(n)$. Am I mistaken? I know that $GL$ stands for general linear transformations but it seems I am missing something else here. Also, in the level of algebras do $Sympl(M,\omega)$ and $Sp(n)$  have anything to do with each other? To add another remark, a vector field $X$ on $M$ is symplectic if it lives in the algebra of $Sp(n)$ or $Sympl(\mathcal{M}, \omega)$?

Comment: 1. A transformation of coordinates is not a diffeomorphism of the entire manifold (unless the entire manifold is covered by one coordinate chart). 2. A coordinate transformation $\varphi$ is not an element of $GL(n)$, however, if $p$ is in the domain of $\varphi$, then $d\varphi_p$ is an invertible linear map. 3. I have no idea in what sense a vector field $X$ can lie in either $Sp(n)$ or $\operatorname{Sympl}(M, \omega)$.

Comment: Well, $X$ can lie in the Lie algebra of $Sp(n)$ not the group itself. This is what I meant.